# What is the problem in IF statement in this code?

Tags: sql, sum, mariadb, max, average

```
select studentid,
sum(score) 'Total',
avg(IF(score>85)) 'Average',
max(score) 'Maximum',
min(score) 'Minimum'
from results
group by studentid;
```

**Error Message:**

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
> near ')) 'Average',
>
> max(score) 'Maximum',

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: There are two solutions, but I worry that you meant some third thing by `avg(IF(score>85))`.  Please explain.  Or give a couple of examples.

Answer (score 2):

You are not using the `if()` function correctly - and you should not be using single quotes to alias the columns in the resultset.

You might want:

```
select 
    studentid,
    sum(score) Total,
    avg(score > 85) Average,
    max(score) Maximum,
    min(score) Minimum
from results
group by studentid;
```

`avg(score > 85)` gives you the ratio of scores that are above 85, as a decimal number between `0` and `1`.

If, on the other hand, you want the average of scores that are above 85, you would do:

```
    avg(case when score > 85 then score end) Average
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the ratio of scores over 85, then use a `case` expression:

```
select studentid, sum(score) as Total,
       avg(case when score > 85 then 1 else 0 end) as ratio_over_85,
       max(score) as Maximum, min(score) as Minimum
from results
group by studentid;
```

Or use the shortcut:

```
       avg( score > 85 ) as ratio_over_85,
```

Also, do not use single quotes for column names; only use them for string and date constants.